# Делаю код на основе видеоурока на ютуб, Нужно сделать на сайт вход и регистрацию с хранением данных в бд mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Проблема в том, что данные не отправляются в бд, запрос mysql возвращается пустым. Бд исполmзую в phpmyadmin.

```
<?php
  $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  if(mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина логина";
    exit();
  } else if(mb_strlen($name) < 3 || mb_strlen($name) > 50) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина имени";
    exit();
  } else if(mb_strlen($pass) < 2 || mb_strlen($pass) > 6) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина пароля (от 2 до 6 символов)";
    exit();
  }

$pass = md5($pass."gfsjsdfhhdf123534");

  $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register-bd');
  $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`)
  VALUES('$login', '$pass', '$name')");

$mysql->close();
header('Location: /site');
 ?>
```

Comment: проверить лог на предмет ошибок. Проверить возвращаемые значения функций.  У каждого урока, конечно, своя цель, но так вообще код не пишут.